# How to get call hierarchy of a method in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm, shortcode

I'm new to WebStorm IDE. I need to find out all the methods that call a specific method `X` (in a JS file)

What is the shortcut used for that purpose?

Answer (score 2):

**Call Hierarchy** is available (**Navigate | Call hierarchy**, `Ctrl+Alt+H` in default keymap), but it only works for ES6 class methods and simple functions and doesn't work for function expressions/member functions. See  [WEB-3605](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-3605) and [WEB-14677](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14677)

Comment: so, as I'm using ES5,it is not possible to call hierarchy call ??

Comment: for ES5, it only works for simplest cases like `function foo() {}; foo();`